# botbuilder v4 nodejs add quick reply facebook messenger in prompt dialog

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, messenger

```
async locationStep(step) {
    await step.context.sendActivity('Please give me your location')
    const reply = MessageFactory.suggestedActions(['Send location'])
    reply.suggestedActions.actions[0].content_type = 'location'
    reply.suggestedActions.actions[0].type = 'location'
    return step.prompt(LOCATION_PROMPT, reply)
}
```

I want to add quick replies FB Messenger when prompt location in botbuilder v4
like this one (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/quick-replies/#best_practices) but it not works. Is there a solution to this? Thank you for helping me!

Comment: The BotBuilder Framework converts `suggestedActions` to a `quick_reply` in the Facebook Messenger Channel, so it is possible to send a `quick_reply`; however, it looks like you are trying to prompt the user with a `quick_reply` for their location. I know in V3 there was a [BotBuilder-Location](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Location) package that would allow you to do this, but I'm not sure if V4 has a similar solution.

Comment: Yes sure! Thank you for your reply. I'm looking for the way implement like Bobuilder-Location of v3 but in v4 like what you said.

Comment: @ThuanNguyen Hi did you find a way to implement this in V4? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In v4 of the Microsoft Botframework, Facebook location quick replies can be sent using the `channelData` attribute in the activity. See the example below.

```
await turnContext.sendActivity({
    text: 'Would you mind sharing your location?',
    channelData: {
        "quick_replies":[
            {
                "content_type": "location"
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

[image]

Hope this helps!